# Robolectric: How to Verify Fragment shows DialogFragment

Tags: android, fragment, robolectric, dialogfragment

I have the following routine that I'm trying to test using Robolectric:

```
/**
 * The add attachment button has been selected, present the picker.
 */
public void onAddAttachment() {
    AttachmentPickerDialog.create(this).show(getFragmentManager(), "attachment");
}
```

So far, my test looks like:

```
@Test
public void onAddAttachment() {
    // Bunch of setup stuff so APD can do it's thing and MessageFragment can do their things

    // Create and start the fragment
    MessageFragment fragment = new MessageFragment();
    fragment.setMessage(new MailMessage(RuntimeEnvironment.application, "http://some.random.com", 32));
    startFragment(fragment);

    // Call I'm actually trying to test
    fragment.onAddAttachment();

    // This verifies that my desired fragment is the top fragment
    List<Fragment> fragments = fragment.getFragmentManager().getFragments();
    AttachmentPickerDialog attachmentPickerDialog = (AttachmentPickerDialog) fragments.get(fragments.size() - 1);

    // And that it got initialized with the correct stuff, really an APD test
    // not an onAddAttachment test
    assertEquals(providers, attachmentPickerDialog.getOptions());

    // How to verify that the fragment dialog showing happened correctly?
    // This verifies that A dialog was created, but not necessarily that
    // it was a result of apd.show
    Dialog dialog = ShadowDialog.getLatestDialog();
    assertNotNull(dialog);
}
```

This all seems to work fine, I can verify that the right fragment is displayed and that it got set up correctly, but I'm struggling with trying to verify the DialogFragment dialog was shown.  Do I even need bother, or is it sufficient to verify that the correct DF is on the top of the fragment stack?